# How to set Canon C5235i printer to staple

Tags: printing, canon

How do you set the options to enable stapling when printing to a [Canon C5235i](http://www.canon.co.uk/For_Work/Products/Office_Print_Copy_Solutions/Office_Colour_Printers/iR_ADV_C5235i/) printer?

I tried looking at `http://localhost:631` but I can't see any option for this.  I am using `Canon imageRunner C6800 Foomatic/Postscript (recommended)` as the printer driver as the closest model I could find.

There is apparently a driver from Canon at http://software.canon-europe.com/software/0044074.asp but when I attempt to install the .deb it says it is for amd64 and refuses to install it.

Comment: If it does not work add it to your q and i'll remove my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

## [GPR](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gpr) [image: Install gpr]

> gpr is a graphical interface to lpr that provides for easy configuration of printer-specific options. gpr interfaces with a PostScript printer's PPD file to create a user-interface of configurable options. Based upon user choice, the device-specific option code is then inserted into the PostScript job and sent to the printer. **This can be used to tell the printer to duplex or staple the print job**, or tell it what paper tray to draw paper from. NOTE: gpr will detect if the file to be print is postscript, and, if not, it will call a2ps to preprocess it before sending it to ppdfilt and to lpr.